# How to make Odoo server action to be visible only for form view and not for tree views?

Tags: xml, odoo, odoo-9

I have a server action that is visible for form and tree views in Action dropdown. I want to remove this server action for tree view. i.e. after selecting records from tree view, this action should not appear in Action dropdown.

Comment: Try with the boolean attribute `multi`. It exists in `ir.actions.server`. In `ir.actions.act_window` model also exists, and if it's *True*, the option only appears under the *More* section in views with multiple records (like kanban or tree) and not in views with a single record (like form). If it's *False*, I guess the option will appear in all views. That's not what you want but you can check the code of the attribute `multi` and try to add your own field to `ir.actions.server`.

Comment: Where to set this attribute (multi) ?